# Error in counting the number of labels for a multi-label classification problem

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, computer-vision

I am attempting to count the distribution of labels for a multi-label classification problem. Please find included a sample data from the CSV file.

```
filenames   labels
tt3302594.jpg   ['deer']
tt2377194.jpg   ['deer']
tt2309762.jpg   ['dog', 'deer']
tt2870808.jpg   ['cat', 'deer']
tt2551396.jpg   ['cat', 'dog', 'deer']
tt4008652.jpg   ['dog']
tt2926810.jpg   ['deer']
tt3531604.jpg   ['dog', 'deer']
tt2290739.jpg   ['cat', 'deer']
```

I am expecting to draw a seaborn plot that takes the individual labels in the X-axis and their count values in the Y-axis.

The following is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from collections import Counter

train = pd.read_csv('example.csv')    # reading the csv file
meta = pd.DataFrame(train, columns=['filenames', 'labels'])
print(f'Found {len(meta)} images')
meta.sample(9)
all_labels = [label for lbs in meta['labels'] for label in lbs]
labels_count = Counter(all_labels)
ax = sns.countplot(all_labels, order=[k for k, _ in labels_count.most_common()], log=True)
ax.set_title('Number of images with a class label')
ax.set_ylim(1E2, 1E4)
ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=90);
```

The above code, instead of counting the number of images with class labels in counting each character in the label like ''', 'd', 'e', 'r' and so on.

Comment: might be that labels values are not lists but strings with brackets in them, if thats the the case use ast.literal)eval() to fix

Comment: @Ezer K Can you please suggest the modification to the code? I am not clear about your comments since I am new to Python coding. Thanks.

Comment: try adding:
import ast; 
meta['labels'] = [ast.literal_eval(x) for x in meta['labels"].values]

Comment: a more general note, try posting text rather than pics (use print or df.to_clipboard())

Comment: @Ezer K: Thanks. Edited the post as recommended. However, when i used your code lines, it throws a value error like this: raise ValueError('malformed node or string: ' + repr(node))

ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Name object at 0x000002034D8777F0>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse the list formed string to real lists with literal_eval (in addition, for the posted sample the y lims will make the bars vanish, so commented), here goes:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from collections import Counter
import ast

train = pd.read_csv('example.csv')    # reading the csv file
meta = pd.DataFrame(train, columns=['filenames', 'labels'])
print(f'Found {len(meta)} images')
meta.sample(9)
meta['labels'] = [ast.literal_eval(x) for x in meta['labels'].values] 
all_labels = [label for lbs in meta['labels'] for label in lbs]
labels_count = Counter(all_labels)
ax = sns.countplot(all_labels, order=[k for k, _ in labels_count.most_common()], log=True)
ax.set_title('Number of images with a class label')
# ax.set_ylim(1E2, 1E4)
ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=90);
```

[image]